# Why I do not can delete the file?

Tags: java, locking

I do not understand why Java don't want to delete the file!
I basically want to lock a file to avoid that my jar-file can start more than one time. Then after the action I want to delete the lock-file, but this seems for some reason not to be possible.

Here is the code:

```
package footballQuestioner;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class attempter 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        Ausgabe ausGabe=new Ausgabe();
    }

    class Ausgabe  
    {
        public Ausgabe() 
        {
           tryToStart();
        }

        public boolean tryToStart(){

            File file1=new File("C:\\Users\\laudatio\\Downloads\\erzFeind.txt");
            RandomAccessFile in=null;
            FileLock fileLock=null;
            file1.setWritable(true);

            try 
            {
               file1.createNewFile();
               in = new RandomAccessFile(file1, "rw");
               fileLock = in.getChannel().tryLock();

               if(fileLock == null)
                 return false;


            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        file1.delete();

        return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried 1- making sure the file exists and 2- Releasing the file lock?

Comment: yes the file exists - how I release the lock?

Comment: [`FileLock#release`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html#release()), which should probably be within the `finally` section of your `try-catch`...just make sure you check for nulls

Comment: The File.createNewFile() call is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete a file you have open. This is a limitation of Windows. You must first close it.  try

```
file1.close();
file1.delete();
```

Note: Unix doesn't do this, it not a Java "feature"

Comment: Yeah that's it! I have to close the RandomAccessFile in!